# Unrecognized Ciphers from mobile application

Tags: c#, android, encryption, exchange-server

I'm writing an Android application with Xamarin (C#) that makes calls to Exchange Web Services. The code sets the out of office message. The code I have written works from a standard Windows Forms application, but fails with a "Request Invalid" SOAP exception. I've captured the requests using Fiddler, and it appears to be a cipher issue.

The Windows Forms request is this:

A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.

Version: 3.1 (TLS/1.0)

Random: 53 B1 31 EF DD 96 01 7E 0A 0A 1F 85 60 8F 2F BD D6 77 08 2D B0 C6 52 91 BC A0 19 2F 20 08 F1

SessionID: empty

Extensions:

renegotiation_info 00

server_name

elliptic_curves    secp256r1 [0x17], secp384r1 [0x18]

ec_point_formats   uncompressed [0x0]

Ciphers:

[002F] TLS_RSA_AES_128_SHA

[0035] TLS_RSA_AES_256_SHA

[0005] SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA

[000A] SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA

[C013] TLS1_CK_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

[C014] TLS1_CK_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA

[C009] TLS1_CK_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

[C00A] TLS1_CK_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA

[0032] TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_SHA

[0038] TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_SHA

[0013] SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA

[0004] SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5

Compression:

[00]   NO_COMPRESSION

The Android request is this:

A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.

Version: 3.1 (TLS/1.0)

Random: 53 B1 30 9C 9A A2 AE 57 A9 98 A3 C8 DF 94 E0 04 1D 3F E1 34 A8 8A DF 8B 5E 8B 60 67 96 6D 1B

SessionID: empty

Extensions:

server_name

Ciphers:

[0035] TLS_RSA_AES_256_SHA

[002F] TLS_RSA_AES_128_SHA

[000A] SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA

[0005] SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA

[0004] SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5

[0009] SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_SHA

[0003] SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5

[0006] SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC2_40_MD5

[0008] SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_SHA

[0060] Unrecognized cipher - See http://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/

[0061] Unrecognized cipher - See http://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/

[0062] TLS_RSA_EXPORT1024_WITH_DES_SHA

[0064] TLS_RSA_EXPORT1024_WITH_RC4_56_SHA

Compression:

[00]   NO_COMPRESSION

The "unrecognized cipher" message leaps out here. Any help on how to resolve this issue would be great.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

That two ciphers are not recognized does not mean that there are no ciphers to choose from. Unless the TLS is explicitly broken down further on, it's likely another issue.

I think you are better off looking at the SOAP messages.

Comment: thanks for this. finally got back to looking at this and there is a difference between the request headers. The Windows app that succeeds is using Negotiate authorization, whereas the mono client that fails is using NTLM. I'm guessing I either need to change the mono client to use negotiate, or enable NTLM on the IIS server.

Comment: Yeah, that could also be an issue. If you find out, it would be helpful if you could post this as an answer.